# Why does Binding.ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors default to true, but every other ValidatesOnXXX to false

Tags: wpf, silverlight

today I wasted about an hour trying to figure out why a control went to "Invalid" state, although no binding used any "ValidatesOnXXX" = true....

The solution was simple: we recently used INotifyDataErrorInfo for the first time (not available in .Net 3.5) and for this interface the error-checking is active as default.

I was used to having to enable error-checking....what's the motivation from MS to suddenly change the default to true (and ONLY for that interface....)...My problem with this is consistency - either default them all to false, or to true, but do not mix it...

Any insights?

#### "Old" way:

```
public class DataClass : IDataErrorInfo 
{ 
    ... 
    
}


<TextBock x:Name="textBoxWithValidation" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBock x:Name="textBoxWithNoValidation" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<!-- IDataErrorInfo is only validating if ValidatesOnDataErrors is explicitly set to True -->
```

#### "New" way:

```
public class DataClass : INotifyDataErrorInfo 
{ 
    ... 
    
}


<TextBock x:Name="textBoxWithValidation" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBock x:Name="textBoxWithNoValidation" Text="{Binding SomeProperty, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<!-- INotifyDataErrorInfo is validating unless you explicitly turn it off -->
```

Also - I think when using INotifyDataErrorInfo object-level errors seem to be finally working (when propertyName is null or empty) - but I need to investigate some more to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when something new comes and supersedes the older solution, the latter is deemed obsolete, legacy and thus irrelevant in context of consistency: it is only consistent not to use it anymore. It is reasonable to default to `true` in this case, cause the interface is intended exactly for UI validation, and, since it's new, no legacy code can contain it and thus no behaviour would be changed silently. If you do implement the interface, you know why you do so.